# How to reset any function in Julia to its original state?

Tags: julia

I am learning Julia, Here is something I am unable to figure out.

Case1: I started Julia console and overridden the default `sqrt` function with a number 10. So now the function doesn't work. To me coming from R its bit of surprise, In R usually even if we override a function it works because of the method dispatch. Clearly, Julia's way of doing it is different which is okay. But now I am unable to reset to its natural state. I have to restart Julia to make it(`sqrt`) work again.

```
julia> sqrt = 10
10

julia> sqrt(5)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

julia> sqrt = Nothing
Nothing

julia> sqrt(5)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Nothing(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Nothing() at boot.jl:324
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

Case2: I started Julia console and used `sqrt` function to calculate things and it worked. But now if I try to reset to a constant it's not working. (I am assuming its because its compiled already and hence can't be overridden).

```
julia> sqrt(7)
2.6457513110645907

julia> sqrt = 10
ERROR: cannot assign a value to variable Base.sqrt from module Main
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
```

*****My question is**:***

**Is there any way to reset the function to original state without restarting Julia?
Also is my assumption for case2 is correct?**

I am not sure if its already answered somewhere. I tried to find it out, but couldn't. I am still giving a read on this thing. But asking for help if anyone knows this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version are you using? My Julia tells me `ERROR: cannot assign a value to variable Base.sqrt from module Main`.

Comment: I am sorry about image. I will fix that in sometime. I am using Julia 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIU, the rationale for this behavior is as follows:

1. when you run `sqrt(5)` in a program, it means that you know about the `sqrt` function. If, later on, you try to assign a new value to `sqrt`, Julia forbids you to do so, on the grounds that `sqrt` in your program actually refers to the `Base.sqrt` function, which is a constant. (Note that the same is true of any function that got exported by a package you're `using`; there is no specificity related to `Base` here, except that you don't have to explicitly `using Base` in order to be able to call the functions it defines).
2. if you don't use `sqrt` first as a function, Julia can't assume that you know about `Base.sqrt`. So if the first mention of `sqrt` in your program is an assignment, it will happily create a new variable of that name. This makes Julia more future-proof: suppose that you write a program that declares and uses a variable named `foo`. As of Julia 1.5.3, no `Base.foo` function exists. But now imagine that Julia 1.6 introduces a `Base.foo` function. We wouldn't want such a change to break your existing code, which should continue working with newer Julia versions. Therefore the safe choice in this case consists in letting you freely declare a variable `foo` without worrying about the name collision with `Base.foo`.

Now in the case where you accidentally create in an interactive session a global variable that collides with an existing function, a simple solution would be to simply reassign your variable to the function from `Base` (or whichever module the original function came from):

```
julia> sqrt = 1
1

# Oops, looks like I made a mistake
julia> sqrt(2)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

# Let's try and fix it
julia> sqrt = Base.sqrt
sqrt (generic function with 20 methods)

julia> sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation also really appreciate for the edits.